# how do create puppet file directory resource using variable in the name so that it does not add brackets around the name []

Tags: linux, puppet, resources, hiera

When I try the following in my manifest.

```
$profile = hiera('duplicity::profile', 'test123')

file { [ "/tmp/${profile}" ]:
  ensure => directory,
  owner  => root,
  group  => root,
}
```

I have the following defined in the heira for that node

```
duplicity::profile:
  - 'testfails'
```

Which creates folders like this

```
find /tmp/\[testfails\]
/tmp/[testfails]
```

Why is it adding the brackets into the folder name?

- https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/latest/lang_variables.html#variable-interpolation
- https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/latest/types/file.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with how I had declared my hiera data.

```
duplicity::profile:
  - 'testfails'
```

That creates a list or array of values. 
It does not make sense to try and create a directory out of list or array. 
I should either iterate through the list or ensure that I only allow single string values.

Where this assigns a single string to the variable.

```
duplicity::profile: 'testthatworks'
```

That correctly creates the directory without `[]`

Comment: can you please mark this as the correct answer and close the question?